# Mongodb and Meteor trying to subscribe using a parameter

Tags: mongodb, meteor, parameter-passing

I want to publish some specific data using this code:

```
Meteor.publish('getMiddlemans', function(price){
    return Middleman.find({"trustValue.euro": {$gt: price} }, {sort: {fee: -1}});
});
```

This code isn't working, but if I change it to that:

```
Meteor.publish('getMiddlemans', function(price){
    return Middleman.find({"trustValue.euro": {$gt: 49} }, {sort: {fee: -1}});
});
```

And this code is working perfectly fine. I don't understand why this parameter "price" is causing me problem here. I verified the value of price and it's indeed 49..

Comment: What does your subscription look like? Should be something like `var middlemen = Meteor.subscribe('getMiddlemans',price);` Also are you verifying that the subscription is ready on the client?

Comment: Yes, my subscription looks exactly like that and the subscription is ready. My second code is working fine, so maybe it's a bug with the parameter? Or I need to call it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is price a string ? If so, try to parse price into integer.

```
price = parseInt(price);
return Middleman.find({"trustValue.euro": {$gt: price} }, {sort: {fee: -1}});
```